# Can anyone assist me with Toulmin's model of argumentation in Philosophy?

Tags: logic, argumentation

i have recently studied about Toulmin’s model of argumentation. But i cannot do some problems of finding what are grounds, warrant,
claim, qualifiers, rebuttals. If anyone can assist me for following sample paragraph taken from [Ludger Jansen](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=a8okaQ1-htgC&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22&dq=The%20ritual%20was%20annually%20repeated%20for%20a%20long%20time,%20and%20hence%20the%20ship%20needed%20continual%20repair,&source=bl&ots=Wnaav_JWIs&sig=TlKiybzixPWRo7w0IvrYz31EOAo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwih3OqA6b3XAhXBxLwKHWmGBGYQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=The%20ritual%20was%20annually%20repeated%20for%20a%20long%20time%2C%20and%20hence%20the%20ship%20needed%20continual%20repair%2C&f=false):

> The “ Ship of Theseus ”is an intriguing puzzle about identity through time.
>   It is based on the custom of the Athenians to send Theseus ’ship each year
>   on a sacred voyage to Delos, because it was believed that Apollo once saved
>   the lives of Theseus and his fourteen fellow - travellers. The ritual was annually
>   repeated for a long time, and hence the ship needed continual repair,
>   new planks being substituted for the old ones. Plutarch relates to us that
>   already the Athenian philosophers had discussed whether the ship is still
>   the same ship although it consists, after a while, entirely of new planks. Hobbes put a sophisticated twist to the story: Suppose, he said, that someone collected the old planks and put them together again in the end, thus restoring the
>   old ship. The same ship, then, seems to exist twice, which is absurd. Hobbes
>   used this argument to support his version of relative identity: the original
>   ship T1 and the restored ship T2 share the same matter, whereas the original
>   ship and the repaired ship T3 share the same form.
>
> > [I]f, for example, that ship of Theseus, concerning the difference whereof
> >     made by continual reparation in taking out the old planks and putting in new,
> >     the sophisters of Athens were wont to dispute, were, after all the planks were
> >     changed, the same numerical ship it was at the beginning; and if some man
> >     had kept the old planks as they were taken out, and by putting them afterwards
> >     together in the same order, had again made a ship of them, this, without
> >     doubt, had also been the same numerical ship with that which was at the
> >     beginning; and so there would have been two ships numerically the same,
> >     which is absurd (Thomas Hobbes [*De Corpore*,](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=DQW9nyBCClMC&pg=PA273&lpg=PA273&dq=the%20same%20numerical%20ship%20it%20was%20at%20the%20beginning;%20and%20if%20some%20man%20had%20kept%20the%20old%20planks%20as%20they%20were%20taken%20out,%20and%20by%20putting%20them%20afterwards%20together%20in%20the%20same%20order,%20had%20again%20made%20a%20ship%20of%20them,%20this,%20without%20doubt,%20had%20also%20been%20the%20same%20numerical%20ship%20with%20that%20which%20was%20at%20the%20beginning;%20and%20so%20there%20would%20have%20been%20two%20ships%20numerically%20the%20same,%20which%20is%20absurd&source=bl&ots=M3nLTYMMnf&sig=OrR08oracdcI17nX7XMfHAd_ZlY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfn9m_6L3XAhUEfrwKHddmD3wQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=the%20same%20numerical%20ship%20it%20was%20at%20the%20beginning%3B%20and%20if%20some%20man%20had%20kept%20the%20old%20planks%20as%20they%20were%20taken%20out%2C%20and%20by%20putting%20them%20afterwards%20together%20in%20the%20same%20order%2C%20had%20again%20made%20a%20ship%20of%20them%2C%20this%2C%20without%20doubt%2C%20had%20also%20been%20the%20same%20numerical%20ship%20with%20that%20which%20was%20at%20the%20beginning%3B%20and%20so%20there%20would%20have%20been%20two%20ships%20numerically%20the%20same%2C%20which%20is%20absurd&f=false) 1655)

Comment: And the question is ?

Comment: See [Ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus) as wella s [Identity over Time](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/identity-time/) as well as [The Ship of Theseus Puzzle](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/material-constitution/#Puz).

Answer (score 3):

*Hint*: see  [Stephen Toulmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Toulmin)'s [Model of Argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Toulmin#The_Toulmin_Model_of_Argument).

*Claim*: A conclusion whose merit must be established.

*Ground (or Data)*: A fact one appeals to as a foundation for the claim.

If you want to apply the model to a "paradox" (like [The Ship of Theseus Puzzle](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/material-constitution/#Puz)), the first thing is to identify the hidden claim.

I suggest this:

> The material constituents of a physical object are **not** the source of the identity of the object.

The argument starts with the *Assumption* that "The material constituents **are** the source of  identity".

Then supplies *Data*:

> "the (real) persistence of the object through physical changes (removal and replace of parts);"
>
> "the (imaginary) prossibility of re-building another copy of the original objects with the removed parts."

Then we have a purported *Conclusion* of the argument: "if the above *experiment* is performed, we would have two ships numerically the same, which is absurd."

Having reached a contradiction, we conclude (by [Reductio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum)) with the negation of the *Assumption*, that amounts to a "poof" of the original *Claim*.